# Is it a loophole to join ldap authentication?

Tags: ldap

If multiple systems join ldap authentication, then any administrator of any one of them can get the password of any user's account.right？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications authenticating against an LDAP directory are not going to be able to access all of the user passwords ***en mass*** provided you do not not permit direct read access to the attribute or you do not store your passwords in clear text (if you use something like ldapsearch to dump an entry and have userpassword:: followed by a bunch of random looking 'stuff', that's an easily decoded clear text password). App I allow to access my LDAP server aren't given access to read all of the userPassword values to attempt reversing them out to clear text (and I'm using a decent encryption mechanism to store userPassword value). I restrict the application service account to reading contact-type attributes (phone number, address) and group objects. The only way they get the user's password is by asking the user for it and binding against my directory with those credentials. Can an app admin grab credentials for those who use the application? Sure, they *could*.

On an out of the box application, I could attach a debugger and access the username/password values as they transit the application. With custom-written applications, it's even easier to grab the credentials. The application takes the username and password as user input and binds to the LDAP server to validate the username and password. As an LDAP server admin, there's nothing I can do to prevent the application developer from making calls and doing *other* things with that username and password. "Other things" may be legit -- I've handled LDAP directory migrations by authenticating against the old system and, on success, creating the user in the new directory LDAP with the password the old directory just accepted. It was an ugly way to migrate directories, but it worked. "Other things" may be malicious. Is it likely to encounter an app admin or developer who is siphoning off credentials? Depends on who authenticating through your LDAP directory.

This isn't a unique failing of LDAP -- any authentication back-end that you let other people use directly suffers from the same problem. If you don't want the app admins/developers intercepting user credentials, look into federated identify management (FIM) -- an authentication mechanisms where the app (service provider, in FIM terminology) ***doesn't*** have access to the username and password but rather validates a token of some sort that was created after a trusted "identity provider" authenticated the username and password.